# Add a payment using quickbooks API?

Tags: c#, api, synchronization, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I'm using the QBFC13 Library to sync QuickBooks and my .NET app.

But I can't seem to find out how can I add a payment to quickbooks from my app.

I've notice that I have this method:

```
IPaymentMethodAdd paymentMehtodAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendPaymentMethodAddRq()
```

But I don't know how to fill the parameters for it to work.

Can somebody please help me with an example of a simple payment passing the: ClientId and the Amount Paid?

Note: I'm using C#.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2 step process.

1. Create a bill
2. Make the Payment

Create a bill;

```
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.getMsgSetRequest();
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

            IBillAdd addBill = requestMsgSet.AppendBillAddRq();
            addBill.VendorRef.FullName.SetValue(vendorName);
            addBill.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now);
            addBill.DueDate.SetValue(dueDate);
            addBill.APAccountRef.FullName.SetValue(accountPayable);
            addBill.Memo.SetValue(accountPayableMemo);

            IExpenseLineAdd expenceLineAdd = addBill.ExpenseLineAddList.Append();
            expenceLineAdd.AccountRef.FullName.SetValue(accountExpenses);
            expenceLineAdd.Amount.SetValue(value);
            expenceLineAdd.Memo.SetValue(accountExpensesLineMemo);

            IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.doRequest(true, ref requestMsgSet)
```

Make the Payment : You can do the payment using cheque or credit card

Credit Card,

```
            IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.getMsgSetRequest();
            requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

            IBillPaymentCreditCardAdd paymentAdd = requestMsgSet.AppendBillPaymentCreditCardAddRq();
            paymentAdd.CreditCardAccountRef.FullName.SetValue("CreditCardAccount");
            paymentAdd.PayeeEntityRef.FullName.SetValue("TestVendor");
            paymentAdd.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Now);
            paymentAdd.Memo.SetValue("test payment credit card");

            IAppliedToTxnAdd appliedToTxnAdd = paymentAdd.AppliedToTxnAddList.Append();
            appliedToTxnAdd.TxnID.SetValue("7D-1509602561");
            appliedToTxnAdd.PaymentAmount.SetValue((double)250.00);


            IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.doRequest(true, ref requestMsgSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Onscreen Reference Guide included with the SDK that has the available parameters and fields.  http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html